# Is there any word for unlisten (negative of listen)?

Tags: negation

I would like to know if is there any word for saying unlisten (not to listen).

**Edit**

I am working on some programming code where the author has named one function `listen()` and another one `unlisten()`. I want to know whether there is a better one-word alternative for 'unlisten'.

Comment: "un-" with verbs usually means "reverse the process". For example "untie a knot". You can't reverse the process of listening.  If you just mean "not listening" then you don't want a word, you just want "don't listen" the usual negation.  So please clarify what exactly you want to express, Please give an example with more context.

Comment: I edited the question @JamesK .

Comment: Oh as a function name, meaning "stop listening", `unlisten` is fine in that context.  But this isn't really about English.

Comment: In the context of programming, it's better to be clear than to try and force "correct" English.  If **listen()** is a function that initiates some listening process, then **unlisten()** (as the function to stop this process) is the best term.  It's immediately obvious that it's the opposite of the other function.  I agree this is really a programming question.

Comment: Are you talking about ***not*** *listening* or about ***undoing*** something you've already listened to?

Comment: @JasonBassford It's about not listening.

Comment: Dont worry about unlisten its ok and usually used in common scripts, for example: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/search?q=unlisten&unscoped_q=unlisten

You can use unListen for skip spell check issues

Answer (score 0):

There is ignore, as in ignore().